# Get user's ISP, country and city by ip?

Tags: ip

How to get user's ISP, country and city by ip without any other service. I looked in some solutions with whatismyipaddress.com but they don't allow anymore http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/194.153.145.104 by curl it returns - `You appear to be an automated script. Site terms and conditions do not allow for automated/script access. For API details see http://whatismyipaddress.com/api`
And their API don't allow to get Geolocation data. Here is what i have tested:

```
$ip='194.153.145.104';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/' . $ip); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$data = explode("\n", curl_exec($curl));

$isp = null;
$country = null;
$city = null;
$MaxIndex = count($data) - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $MaxIndex; $i++){
    if (strpos($data[$i], '<th>ISP:</th>') !== false){
        $isp = str_replace('<td>', '', $data[$i + 1]);
        $isp = str_replace('</td>', '', $isp);
        break;
    }

    if (strpos($data[$i], '<th>Country:</th>') !== false){
        $country = str_replace('<td>', '', $data[$i + 1]);
        $country = str_replace('</td>', '', $country);
        break;
    }

    if (strpos($data[$i], '<th>City:</th>') !== false){
        $city = str_replace('<td>', '', $data[$i + 1]);
        $city = str_replace('</td>', '', $city);
        break;
    }
}
print_r($data);
echo "ISP: ".$isp."<br />Country: ".$country."<br />City: ".$city;
```

Comment: Data with such accuracy is hard to build. You probably need to look at the databases built by companies like MaxMind.

Comment: Can you offer me any free solution?

Comment: Maxmind has some free databases

Answer (score -1):

They probably check if the User-Agent header in the request is that of a valid Browser.

Add this to your script and it should work:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Comment: @Sander Steffann sure, but that was not the question. I provided a technical solution to a technical problem - this is not a law site.

Comment: True, but I thought it needed to be mentioned :)

Comment: That is violate whatismyipaddress.com's conditions, so that is not an option.